# How to get Next JS dynamic routing working with RelayJS

Tags: routes, next.js, relayjs

I am trying to switch our routing to NextJS's v9 [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), moving off the previous [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes) library.

From playing around and looking at the docs, it seems to enforce a certain file structure if I was to pass in a parameter/slug. e.g. for a blog post

```
blog
  [slug].tsx
```

Would allow me to use a route like `blog/id123`.

We use RelayJS, which also has a reliance on the file name. In this case, all React components must name queries in the format `FileNameQuery`. This would mean I'd need to name all my Relay queries after the variable name I am passing in, which isn't going to scale well.

Has anyone managed to get these working well together?

Answer (score 1):

withData.js in example [with-relay-modern](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/0890b586f4b7c74ebbe072c2519e1e4fd5e0a4ea/examples/with-relay-modern)

```
if (options.query) {
  // Provide the `url` prop data in case a graphql query uses it
  // const url = { query: ctx.query, pathname: ctx.pathname }
  const variables = ctx.query
    ? Object.assign((options.variables || {}), ctx.query)
    : (options.variables || {})
  // const variables = options.variables || { }
  // const cacheConfig = { force: true }
  // TODO: Consider RelayQueryResponseCache
  // https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1687#issuecomment-302931855
  queryProps = await fetchQuery(environment, options.query, variables) // , cacheConfig
  queryRecords = environment
    .getStore()
    .getSource()
    .toJSON()
}
```

**`const variables = ctx.query
    ? Object.assign((options.variables || {}), ctx.query)
    : (options.variables || {})`**